# How to open/close sidebar in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce, editor, wysiwyg, sidebar

In the official TinyMCE docs is nothing written about the possibility to manually open/close the sidebar:
https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/creating-a-sidebar/#editorsidebarapi

Can anybody help me? I think it must be something like this:

```
editor.getSidebar('mysidebar').close();
```

I need it, because I want to close my custom sidebar in my [file browser callback](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/file-image-upload/#file_browser_callback).

Answer (score 2):

Use `tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('togglesidebar', false, 'sidebarname');` to toggle the sidebar. You could place event dispacthers and listeners to know if it is currently opened or closed:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('cheminfo', function (editor, url) {
    editor.ui.registry.addSidebar('cheminfo', {
    tooltip: 'My sidebar',
    icon: 'comment',
    onShow: function (api) {
      var event = new CustomEvent('tinymce-chem-sidebar', {'detail': true});
      window.parent.document.dispatchEvent(event);
    },
    onHide: function (api) {
      var event = new CustomEvent('tinymce-chem-sidebar', {'detail': false});
      window.parent.document.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
    });
});
```

Then (I am using React):

```
// detect sidebar state open/close
document.addEventListener('tinymce-chem-sidebar', function (e) {
  setOpen(e.detail);
});
```

PS: Make sure the sidebar's name is lowercase or it won't work

Answer (score 0):

adding to @Kristiyan Tsvetanov's solution, an alternative to using event listeners in determining open/close state of sidebar, the following code can be used:

```
function is_sidebar_open() {

        //class names taken from using inspect on the 
        //sidebar area of the editor in a browser session

        if ($(".tox-sidebar__slider").hasClass("tox-sidebar--sliding-closed")) {
           
            return false;
        }
        else {
           
            return true;
        }
    }

function open_sidebar(){

    if (is_sidebar_open() == false){
        tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('togglesidebar', false, 'sidebarname');
    }
}

function close_sidebar(){

    if (is_sidebar_open() == true){

        tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('togglesidebar', false, 'sidebarname');
    }

}
```